# Duplicate Values in For Loop

Tags: python

when I print "amount", I am getting duplicate values. Does this have to do with two for loops back to back on my first three lines?

missing_amount:

```
['102,131.49']
```

expected results:

```
102,131.49
```

actual results:

```
102,131.49
102,131.49
```

code:
body_l = []
for link in url:
body = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Total:')]").text
body_l.append(body)
icl_dollar_amount = re.findall('(?:[\£$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', body)[0].split('$', 1)[1]
icl_dollar_amount_l.append(icl_dollar_amount)
if not missing_amount:
logging.info("List is empty")
print("List is empty")
count = 0
for amount in missing_amount:
for count, item in enumerate(icl_dollar_amount_l):
if amount == item:
body = body_l[count]
get_company_id = body.split("Customer Id:", 1)[1][4:10].strip()
else:
amount_ack_missing_l.append(amount)
logging.info("Missing " + str(amount))
print("Missing " + str(amount))

With AgentJRock code:

when I print(icl_dollar_amount[i]) and missing_amount[i] my if statement never runs only the else runs. But both list have the same values, please see below.

```
for i in range(len(missing_amount)):
    print("Missing Amount : ", missing_amount[i])
    print("ICL DOLLAR", icl_dollar_amount_l[i])
    if missing_amount[i] == icl_dollar_amount_l[i]:
        body = body_l[i]
        get_company_id = body.split("Customer Id:", 1)[1][4:10].strip()
    else:
        amount_ack_missing_l.append(missing_amount[i])
        logging.info("Missing " + str(missing_amount[i]))
        print("Missing " + str(missing_amount[i]))
```

print(icl_dollar_amount[i]

```
ICL DOLLAR 2,760,127.58
ICL DOLLAR 325,845.84
```

print(missing_amount[i])

```
Missing Amount :  325,845.84
Missing Amount :  2,760,127.58
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, the inner loop is getting your missing_amount twice.

What type/values are in missing amount, icl_dollar_amount_l, and body_l?

Going off missing values is a list of ints
and icl_dollar_amount_l is another list ints
and bod_l is a dictionary

you might be best doing a single for loop to create an index from a range of the length of your lists. From this index in the for loop, you can compare indexes between two lists of shared indices. I think you're trying to share this index with your dict, which should be no problem with the same index we created

also, You have a count variable outside the for loop but have set another instance of count to the enumerate variable.

the outside count needs to be used with a (+=/-+) set to that variable which is equivalent to the enumerate and redundant.

```
for i in range(len(missing_amount)):
    if missing_amount[i] == icl_dollar_amount_l[i]:
        body = body_l[i]
        get_company_id = body.split("Customer Id:", 1)[1][4:10].strip()
    else:
        amount_ack_missing_l.append(missing_amount[i])
        logging.info("Missing " + str(missing_amount[i]))
        print("Missing " + str(missing_amount[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you. My If statement now never runs or is true. My output when i run print(missing_amount[i] and print(icl_dollar_amount[i] is in my edited post

Comment: also, body_l is a list. I was appending the body. See my edited code.

Comment: Awesome, Im glad you figured it out and I could help

Comment: If you could help a fellow programmer out and click the check to accept my answer that'd be super appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you do `print("Missing " + str(amount))`, but also `logging.info("Missing " + str(amount))`. I don't know what logging.info does, but i assume it prints to stdout. I'd recommend you to remove the `print("Missing " + str(amount))`